# Angular2 passing a function to a directive via attribute

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-directives

I'm trying to bind a function in a parent component into a property on a child component.

This is what I have

```
@Component({
  selector: 'awesome',
  templateUrl: 'awesome.html'
})
export class AwesomeComponent {

@Input() callback: Function;

ngOnInit() {

    this.callback();//Error, this.callback is not a function,  but contains a string value on the fuction call
    }
}
```

This is how i'm using it

```
<awesome callback="nameOfFuncFromAnotherComponent"></awesome>
```

but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code only binds the string `nameOfFuncFromAnotherComponent` to the `callback` attribute (and property if it exists). Angular doesn't interpret the value at all.

To make Angular manage the binding use

```
<awesome [callback]="nameOfFuncFromAnotherComponent"></awesome>
```

With this syntax Angular also evaluates the value

```
<awesome callback="{{nameOfFuncFromAnotherComponent}}"></awesome>
```

but converts the result to a string (calls `.toString()`) before the assignment.

Thanks to @MarkRajcok for clarification :)

Comment: Since component `awesome` has a `callback` input property declared, `callback="nameOfFuncFromAnotherComponent"` will bind the string `nameOfFuncFromAnotherComponent` to the `callback` _property_ of the component (not the attribute).  This is some sort of Angular shortcut/special syntax for constants (that I don't like).

Comment: @StevenYates, `callback="{{nameOfFuncFromAnotherComponent}}"` won't work because it essentially calls `nameOfFuncFromAnotherComponent.toString()` and assigns that to the `callback` property.  `{{}}` binding always assigns a string result.

Comment: @MarkRajcok thanks a lot for your insightful explanations!

Comment: How to do if the function has parameters?

Comment: There is no difference. The difference is when you later call the function, then you have to pass parameters. Here only a reference to the function is passed.

Answer (score 7):

i think using eventEmitter in the case of function is much more better becouse of the passing the function by reference will make some problems with the **this**

so my suggestion is to do the following

**cm1.component.html**

```
<cm2-component (childFunc)="myFunc()"></cm2-component>
```

**cm2.component.ts**

```
import { Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
export class Cm2 {
  @Output('childFunc') childFunc: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() { }
  invokeMyFunc(){
    this.childFunc.emit()
  }
}
```

Comment: I also like the eventEmitter approach. I had a problem with this too but it can be overcome by turning a parent function into a delegate.

Answer (score 1):

There is really no need for pushing callback into @Input property.
You can use #local_variable wich provides a reference to the child component.
That way you will have access to all its properties and methods from the parent template.
[See ng2 documentation on component interaction.](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child-local-var)

Comment: if I'm not mistaken, he's looking for the opposite communication flow where the child component calls a method of the parent. So, the parent passes its function to the child.

Answer (score 0):

For me this solution worked:

`<cm2-component [childFunc]="myFunc.bind(this)"></cm2-component>`

```
import { Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
export class Cm2 {
  @Input('childFunc') childFunc: Function;
  constructor() { }
  invokeMyFunc(){
    this.childFunc()
  }
}
```