# Controlling the evaluation of the value of an attribute

Tags: angular

The following code works (modulo any typos -- the real code is much more complicated).  The value of the expression is displayed in an alert when you click on the DOM element containing this directive.

```
@Directive({selector: '[alertOnClick]'})
export class AlertOnClick implements OnDestroy {
  @Input('alertOnClick') clickFunction: (() => string);

  @HostListener('click')
  onClick() {
    alert(this.clickFunction());
  }
}
```

The problem is, it has to be invoked like this:

```
<button [alertOnClick]="() => String(new Date())">Time</button>
```

*Edit: it seems that the Angular parser doesn't support anonymous functions.  It has to be invoked by naming a function on the controller.*

I want to invoke it more naturally, something like this:

```
<button [alertOnClick]="String(new Date())">Time</button>
```

But if any variation like that, the same time will be displayed whenever the button is clicked, the time the page was rendered.  I cannot for the life of me figure out how to evaluate the expression at the time I like, rather than when the page is rendered.  Any suggestions?

Comment: So, you want to pass arbitrary values, not limited to what Angular expressions support? That seems like a bad idea. Modern JavaScript use imported classes/variables from modules, not global variables, so you won't be able to pass anything using not globally defined classes. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If you simply want to pass an angular expression, just change the type of the input to `any`, rename it to something like `message`, and use `alert(this.message);`: http://plnkr.co/edit/3DTNuJAx4fUAH6Umy4nF?p=preview

Comment: @JBNizet -- Hahaha, I see your confusion.  Since my example showed a function without side-effects, you thought it would be OK to call it whenever, so long as it was called immediately before the alert.  Your `now()` function gets called over and over and over.  See here: http://plnkr.co/edit/UFQyg9lkhW5ry3eFnXe4 -- I need to control when it is executed, because it has side-effects.

Comment: So, basically, you want <button (click)="doSomething()">?

Comment: @JBNizet --  I do, but I need the component to have access to to the return value of "doSomething()"

Comment: Please, edit your question, and elaborate. Explain what you really want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible ways to create args:

- `<button [alertOnClick]="method(new Date())">Time</button>` creates `Date` object only once during render/change detection.
- `<button [alertOnClick]="method(createDate())">Time</button>` - creates `Date` object multiple times on each change detection + actual function call.

It is possible to create args in a controlled manner using factory function/type constructor: `<button [alertOnClick]="method(createDate/Date)">Time</button>` and inside `method` will be call `createDate()` or `new date()`. Usable solution, but not convenient.

Another approach is to write pure custom `args` pipe: `<button [alertOnClick]="method|args:[Date,new Date()]">Time</button>`. This pipe creates wrapper function which can create arguments on function invocation. You can control which values should be created once and which should be created only during function invocation. Example:

```
@Pipe({name: 'args', pure: true})
export class ArgsPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(method: Function, parameters: any[]): Function {
    return ()=> {
       const args = parameters.forEach(arg => {
            if(typeof arg === 'function') {
                return arg();
            }
            return arg;
       });
       //todo: figure out how to get correct this
       method.apply(this, args);
    };
  }
}
```

Probably you will need one more pipe to disable evaluation of function arguments, it will transform them into `() => functionArgument`: `<button [alertOnClick]="method|args:[someCallback|func,new Date()]">Time</button>` - in this case `someCallback` function will be passed to `method` without invocation.

Answer (score 0):

### Expression evaluation

> I want to invoke it more naturally, something like this:
> `<button [alertOnClick]="String(new Date())">Time</button>`

This looks to me like late expression evaluation, and can be implemented with

```js
<p alertOnClick="String(new Date())">Current time</p>

@Directive({selector: '[alertOnClick]'})
export class AlertOnClick {
  @Input('alertOnClick') message: String;

  @HostListener('click')
  onClick() {
    alert(eval(this.message));
  }
}
```

What's happening is at compile time the `alertOnClick` property is given a string version of the expression, and then at runtime Javascript eval (ref [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)) is evaluating the string.

***BUT*** of course this is likely to fail with your 'side-effect' code because of binding. i.e `eval` works *only* because `String` and `Date` are built in to the language.
It would be interesting to get an idea of what your side-effects are.

You can also invoke a global function of your own definition

```js
const evalMe = () => { return String(new Date()) }

<p alertOnClick="evalMe()">Current time</p>

@Directive({selector: '[alertOnClick]'})
export class AlertOnClick {
  @Input('alertOnClick') message: String;

  @HostListener('click')
  onClick() {
    alert(eval(this.message));
  }
}
```

This brings into scope plain javascript libraries that might be imported.

### Method evaluation

The 'Angular way' is to pass a method name for future evaluation.
This is shown in a number of places, so I'm surprised you didn't get to it in your example plunker. (Ref: [Angular2 passing a function to a directive via attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35366048/angular2-passing-a-function-to-a-directive-via-attribute))

```js
<p [alertOnClick]="evalMethod">Current time</p>

export class App {
  ...    
  evalMethod() {
    console.log("I am being called!")
    return new Date();
  }


@Directive({selector: '[alertOnClick]'})
export class AlertOnClick {
  @Input('alertOnClick') messageFn: Function;

  @HostListener('click')
  onClick() {
    alert(this.messageFn());
  }
}
```

How well this works depends on the source of your expression, and if any required binding can be done within the component method.
At minimum, you have more scope for binding as you've effectively removed the expression out of the template.

Here's the working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/d8IklvhPfcFkoXS0WScc?p=preview)